# Java Interfaces and their use in Collections

Tags: java, collections, interface

I'm developing a Java library and I need to create a method which returns a `Set<A>`, where `A` is an interface and `B implements A`. So I tried instantiating the set like:

```
Set<A> setOfA = new HashSet<B>();
```

getting the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashSet<B> to Set<A>
```

However, when not using a collection and returning `B` in a function which expects `A` as return type everything is ok, so the relation between the interface and its concrete class is ok and the problem is with collections, the HashSet in this case. How can I avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be `new HashSet<A>();` or `new HashSet<>();`. You can still store B inside these HashSets.

Comment: If you need to return a `Set<A>`, why are you instantiating a `HashSet<B>`?

Comment: @shmosel No, I'm not confused about inheritance "direction" and I know that, in my case, a `Set<B>` is not a `Set<A>`.
@Compass You're right, it works in this way, I'll continue the discussion about this in the similiar answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're asking why `HashSet<B>` is not assignable to `Set<A>`, even though `B` is assignable to `A`. If that's not your question, please clarify.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I was strongly differentiating _being the same_ with _being assignable to_, but I'm now understanding better thanks to the linked question's answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this only:

```
Set<A> setOfA = new HashSet<>();
```

It's a short way of this:

```
Set<A> setOfA = new HashSet<A>();
```

So whan you need to use special methods from B, just do cast like this (if you are sure, that this object is really instance of B)

```
B b = (B) setofA.get(....);
```

You can read pretty good tutorial [here](http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/java-object-typecasting). Good luck